# SQL Server Insert Random

Tags: sql-server, random

i have this table:

```
Create Table Person
(
Consecutive Integer Identity(1,1),
Identification Varchar(15) Primary Key,
)
```

The Identification column can contain letters, numbers, and is optional, i.e., the customer can enter it or not, if not, creates a number automatic.. how can i do to insert a random number that does not exist before?, preferably a lower number.

A example could be:

```
Select Random From Person Where Random Not Exists In Identification
```

This is my code:

```
Select Min(Convert(Integer,Identification)) - 1 
From Person 
Where IsNumeric(Identification) = 1
```

Or

```
Select Max(Convert(Integer,Identification)) + 1 
From Person 
Where IsNumeric(Identification) = 1
```

Works well, but if the customer enter a number high, for example 1000, or higher, then the number will begin from there could have an overflow error

But if there is not a number below Identification and greater than 0 then well be -1, -2, -3.. etc.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: make c onsecutive the primary key, put an index on identification, you are making yourself a world of hurt with this idea

Comment: It's not clear what the endgame is here. If you just need an integer assigned to the person, use an identity column (which, btw, can be incremented backwards). If you need a random value assigned to them, you could use a guid (generated by the newid() function). Consider whether your number NEEDS to be random, or whether it just needs to be unique.

Comment: NEVER!!! let the customer enter the primary key of your table from a UI. You can still have them "choose" a unique number (like choosing your user name when registering with a site), but ALWAYS keep your own internal value as the primary key. I'm with @Xndni, auto increment is the way to go.

Comment: Well, really the table is Article, there are items that have reference/code and others not, so for those who have no reference/code is automatically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what **M.Ali** said. But you can just make use of the below code, but still I don't recommend beyond what **M.Ali** said.

The loop with continue until a random number is generated which is not in your table. You can change the precision to 5 digits by changing `1000` to `10000` and so on.

```
DECLARE @I INT = 0
DECLARE @RANDOM INT;

WHILE(@I=0)
BEGIN       

    SELECT @RANDOM = 1000 + (CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3)) % 1000);

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Identification FROM YOURTABLE WHERE Identification = CAST(@RANDOM AS VARCHAR(4)))
    BEGIN

        -- Do your stuff here       
        BREAK;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         -- The ELSE part
    END 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a Random number of VARCHAR(15), which depends on end user's input can be a very expensive approach when you also want it to be unique.

Imagine a scenario when you have some decent amount of rows say 10,000 rows in this table and a user comes in trying to insert a Random number, chances are the user maybe try 5, 10 or even maybe 15 times to get a unique random value.

On each failed attempt a call will be made to server, a search will be done on table (more rows more expensive this query will become), and the more (failed) attempts a user makes more disappointment/poor application experience user will have.

Would you ever go back to an application(web/windwos) where just for registeration you had struggle this many time? obviously not.

The moral of the story is if you are asking a user to enter some random value, do not expect users to maintain your database integrity and keep that column unique, take control and pair that value with another column which will definately be random. In your case it can be the Identity column. Or alternately you can generate that value for user yourself, using guid.

Comment: Well, really the table is Article, there are items that have reference/code and others not, so for those who have no reference/code is automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) +1 from Person
```

This generates a logical ID for `Identification` that sets the ID to what it 'would have been' with a simple incrementor.
However, you then cannot delete records; instead you must deactivate them, or clear the row.

Alternately, have a separate (hidden) column that only auto-increments, and if `Identification` is left empty, use the value from the hidden column. Same result, but less risk if deletion is relevant.